# Как называть жительницу города Щекино

Tags: род

Здравствуйте! Я родился и проживаю в городе Щекино Тульской области. Таким образом, я - коренной **щекинец**. Моя соседка тоже родилась и проживает в этом городе. Можно ли назвать ее **щекинкой**? Или слово "щекинец" не склоняется по родам?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что Вы совершенно правы, жительница города Щекино называется щекинка.
У нас в Крыму есть поселок Щелкино - звучит очень похоже. И вот его жителя называют щелкинец, а жительницу щелкинка.
Думаю, в Вашем случае все так же.